# Facebook Session: an attempt was made to request new permissions for a session that has a pending request

Tags: android, facebook-sdk-3.0, android-facebook

I am using the following function to post to Facebook. However at times I am getting Unsupported operation exception, related to permissions:

What is the right way to do this? Here's my code :

```
public void postFB(String id) {
        System.out.println("in fb");
        if (isNetworkConnected()) {
            System.out.println("Connected");
            Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
            if (session != null) {
                if(isLoggedIn()){
                    System.out.println("session not null");
                    if (hasPublishPermission()) {
                        System.out.println("Has publish");
                        Bundle params = new Bundle();
                        params.putString("name", " something");
                        params.putString("link", "http://www.examsample.com/");
                        params.putString("picture","http://www.exam_logo.png");
                        params.putString("to", id);
                        params.putString("caption", "Congrulations!");
                        params.putString("description", textGreeting);
                        params.putString("message", "message");


                        WebDialog feedDialog = (new WebDialog.FeedDialogBuilder(
                                getActivity(), Session.openActiveSessionFromCache(getActivity()),
                                params)).setOnCompleteListener(
                                        new OnCompleteListener() {

                                            @Override
                                            public void onComplete(Bundle values,
                                                    FacebookException error) {
                                                // frag3.setFbId(null);
                                                // ---------------------------- got to put
                                                // check here
                                                //  onBackPressed();

                                            }
                                        }).build();
                        feedDialog.show();
                    } else if (session.isOpened()) {
                        // We need to get new permissions, then complete the action
                        session.requestNewPublishPermissions(new Session.NewPermissionsRequest(
                                getActivity(), PERMISSION));
                        Bundle params = new Bundle();
                        params.putString("name", "Something");
                        params.putString("link", "http://www.examsample.com/");
                        params.putString("picture","http://www.exam_logo.png");
                        params.putString("to", id);
                        params.putString("caption", "Congrulations!");
                        params.putString("description", textGreeting);
                        params.putString("message", "message");

                        WebDialog feedDialog = (new WebDialog.FeedDialogBuilder(
                                getActivity(), Session.getActiveSession(),
                                params)).setOnCompleteListener(
                                        new OnCompleteListener() {

                                            @Override
                                            public void onComplete(Bundle values,FacebookException error) {
                                                // frag3.setFbId(null);
                                                // ---------------------------- got to put
                                                // check here
                                                //onBackPressed();

                                            }
                                        }).build();
                        feedDialog.show();
                    }
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Please check if you are logged in", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    mainFrag.setParam(1); 

                    Intent mainIntent;
                    mainIntent = new Intent(getActivity(),FacebookMain.class); 
                    getActivity().startActivity(mainIntent);
                }
            }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Please check your internet connection", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
```

This is my isLoggedIn() function:

```
public boolean isLoggedIn() {
        Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
        if (session != null && session.isOpened()) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Here is the stack trace:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Session: an attempt was made to request new permissions for a session that has a pending request
```